# How to make a counter using a canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a counter so that every time you click your mouse it shows the number of clicks in the canvas.  But it isn't updating the canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>


<button onclick="function1()">Click Here</button>

<script>
var animate = setInterval(window.requestAnimationFrame,1)

var clicks = 0;
        function function1()
        {
        clicks++;
        document.getElementById('myCanvas').innerHTML = clicks;
        }; 
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.font="16px Verdana";
ctx.fillText("Score: " + clicks,190,20);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed the code to add a `redraw()` function to redraw on the canvas the new number.

And the `increment()` function will call that one after doing `clicks++`.

```
var clicks = 0;
function increment(){
    clicks++;
    redraw();
};
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
console.log(ctx);
function redraw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.font="16px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Score: " + clicks,190,20);
}
redraw();
```

You can't just use `innerHTML` for canvas because it is really just a surface for drawing on thus it is not affected by it's inner DOM.

Here is a [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/tHnTL/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code throws an error, `window.requestAnimaitonFrame` requires a callback to a function as parameter. This code works:

```
var animate = setInterval(function(){update()},1)

var clicks = 0;
    function function1()
    {
    clicks++;
    }; 
function update(){

    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    ctx.font="16px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText("Score: " + clicks,190,20);
}
```

Comment: This is *really* resource-intensive without any purpose.  Constantly running `requestAnimationFrame` burns up the CPU.

Comment: I know, but I couldn't be certain that the counter would be the only thing wanted on canvas. Your answer is the best matching this particular requirement though

Comment: `<canvas>` can only be erased and re-drawn.  Not edited one thing at a time (kinda like a artist's canvas).   You might want to consider using [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)?